# How to convert total station data (coordinates) to 3D model?

Tags: qgis, csv, 3d

i have my coordinates in .csv format and i want to convert it to a usable 3D model.

How do i go about this or what software can i use to achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain what you have in mind with the 3D model? QGIS and most GIS software is 2D, but can do some calculation with height data. For 3D visualization, tools like Blender or Povray would be better suited.

Comment: also a small snippet of the csv attributes/values would help .

Answer (score 1):

This is a process that takes several stages.

1) You need to turn the coordinates into shapes. Any good GIS can do this; in the case of QGIS just add the data using the "Add delimited data". Tutorial: http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_csv.php

2) Then you need to turn it into a 3d model. This is more problematic. QGIS has poor/no real 3D support. As you don't specify what format of 3D model, this is open to interpretation.

- There's a plugin for adding it to Sketchup - http://sketchuptips.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/shapefile-importing-plugin-pure-ruby.html
- ArcGIS can do it by converting it to a 3D Shapefile.
- For traditional 3d modelling (3DstudioMax, VIZ, Rhino, etc), a tutorial is here: http://dmg.caup.washington.edu/Reports/GIS-to-3DS/index.html

Also, you can also do this entire process within FME easily:

CSV reader -> VertexCreator -> PointConnector -> LineCloser -> 3DExtruder -> Output to format of your choice! Done.